# WPFのxamlでのバインドをビハインドクラス以外に行いたい

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

こんばんは。
タイトル通りなのですが、XAML内のTextBlockのテキストをビハインドクラス以外の
別の任意のクラスからバインドすることは可能でしょうか。

あるXAML内のTextBlockのテキストを任意のクラスから書き換えたいです。

Answer (score 1):

XAML内のTextBlockのテキストを任意のクラスからバインドすることは可能です。
「WPF DataContext Binding」などで検索するとバインディングやMVVMに関するWebページが見つかります。

- [C# WPFのバインディング　その１](https://araramistudio.jimdo.com/2016/11/25/wpf%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%91/)
- [WPF MVVM textbox text binding vs changedText event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20089739)

下記のWpfApp1.csprojのサンプルコードで目的の動作に沿うでしょうか。
xamlの`UpdateSourceTrigger`を削除すると、ロストフォーカスした時にTextBlockの書き換えが発生します。

`INotifyPropertyChanged`が記述されていないと、ソースからテキストを変更したことをコントロールが感知することができません。
サンプルコードではTimerを使ってTickメソッドからテキストを変更しています。
Tickメソッドでコメントアウトされている★のコードを有効にしてもテキストは変わりませんが、`INotifyPropertyChanged`イベントが実装されているとコードからのテキスト変更が反映されます。

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Name="MyStackPanel">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SimpleText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SimpleText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NotifyText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Timer MyTimer;
        private SimpleModel MySimpleModel = new SimpleModel();
        private NotifyModel MyNotifyModel = new NotifyModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MySimpleModel.SimpleText = "ここに入力するとラベルが書き換わります。";
            MyStackPanel.DataContext = MySimpleModel;
            DataContext = MyNotifyModel;
            MyTimer = new Timer(Tick, null, 0, 1000);

        }

        private void Tick(object state)
        {
            // ★SimpleModelではソースから値を変更しても変わらない(値の変更がxamlに通知されない)
            //MySimpleModel.SimpleText = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            // NotifyModelではソースから値を変更すると表示も変更される
            MyNotifyModel.Next();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleModel
    {
        public string SimpleText { get; set; }
    }

    public class NotifyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string NotifyText
        {
            get { return Text; }
            set
            {
                Text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NotifyText));
            }
        }
        private string Text;
        private int Count = 0;

        public void Next()
        {
            Count++;
            Count = (Count > 5) ? 0 : Count;
            NotifyText = new string('■', Count);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));  //C# 6.0以降有効な上記2行の書き換え(Null条件演算子)
        }
    }
}
```